# AVFoundation: on-the-fly compositions?

Tags: avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, avvideocomposition

Can `AVFoundation` be used to create compositions on the fly?

Scenario: I have five 10-second H.264 clips that I want to play with a nice 1-second fade/transition between them.  Is there a means to create a composition with the first two, begin playing the composition, then add the third while the composition is playing?  Also, deleting the stale/viewed clips from the composition as they're no longer needed would be desirable.

I can't find anything in the API (eg. "`AVMutableVideoComposition`") that permits "mutable" transitions on-the-fly.

My requirements are to create a playlist... that could consist of many (eg. 200) short video elements, all played in sequence with transitions between each.  I also suspect that `AVQueuePlayer` could be brought to bear on this.

An alternate solution would be to create a pair of `AVPlayer`/`AVPlayerLayer` objects that could overlap and would, in effect, play alternating `AVAssets`.

My need would be to intercept video/audio frames as they're playing via `CMSampleBuffer` and a `CVPixelBufferRef` and apply real-time video effects as well.